# Add icon tray on Windows using native Golang API

Tags: windows, go, systray

I'm developing a daemon with no UI apart from a simple icon in the Windows systray.

I would like to have no dependencies on any other package(s), so I'm trying to use the `syscall` package and implement the necessary call(s) by myself.

## Documentation

- After some research, I think that I must use the [`Shell_NotifyIcon`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762159(v=vs.85).aspx) function in `shell32.dll`.
- [The Golang WIKI gives three ways to call a Windows DLL](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/WindowsDLLs). The third solution is to be excluded. For many reasons, I want to build sources with the Golang compiler only.
- I found [an interesting article on "Developing for Multiple Platforms With Go"](https://techblog.steelseries.com/2014/04/08/multi-platform-development-go.html) which explained how to use `Shell_NotifyIconW` (Unicode declination), but the implementation is partial.
- I have found a few Golang libraries which implement Windows System Tray. They are useful to help understand the structure and calls involved in dealing with it.

### Libraries

- [getlantern/systray](https://github.com/getlantern/systray)
- [cratonica/trayhost](https://github.com/cratonica/trayhost)
- [xilp/systray](https://github.com/xilp/systray)
- [lxn/walk](https://github.com/lxn/walk)

## Implementation

### Structures

Built with [xilp/systray documentation](https://gowalker.org/github.com/xilp/systray).

```
type HANDLE uintptr

type HICON HANDLE
    type HWND HANDLE

type GUID struct {
    Data1 uint32
    Data2 uint16
    Data3 uint16
    Data4 [8]byte
}

type NOTIFYICONDATA struct {
    CbSize           uint32
    HWnd             HWND
    UID              uint32
    UFlags           uint32
    UCallbackMessage uint32
    HIcon            HICON
    SzTip            [128]uint16
    DwState          uint32
    DwStateMask      uint32
    SzInfo           [256]uint16
    UVersion         uint32
    SzInfoTitle      [64]uint16
    DwInfoFlags      uint32
    GuidItem         GUID
}
```

### Variables

```
const (
    NIM_ADD = 0x00000000
    NIM_MODIFY = 0x00000001
    NIM_DELETE = 0x00000002
    NIM_SETVERSION = 0x00000004

    NIF_MESSAGE = 0x00000001
    NIF_ICON = 0x00000002
    NIF_TIP = 0x00000004
    NIF_STATE = 0x00000008

    NIF_HIDDEN = 0x00000001
)
```

### Source

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "syscall"
    "unsafe"
)

func main() {
    shell32 := syscall.MustLoadDLL("shell32.dll")
    Shell_NotifyIcon := shell32.MustFindProc("Shell_NotifyIconW")

    iconData := NOTIFYICONDATA{
        HWnd: 0,
        UFlags: NIF_MESSAGE | NIF_STATE,
        DwState: NIF_HIDDEN,
        DwStateMask: NIS_HIDDEN,
    }
    iconData.CbSize = uint32(unsafe.Sizeof(iconData))

    ret, _, _ := Shell_NotifyIcon.Call(
        NIM_ADD,
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&iconData)),
    )

    if ret == 0 {
        log.Println("Failed")
        return
    }

    // Do anything, like open a HTTP server to keep the program running
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

### Details

- I have no idea what information to give in `HWnd`, but without it, the executable crashes.
- `UFlags`, `DwState` and `DwStateMask` have values that I have found in different projects.

I know that it is possible; the [Golang WIKI](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/WindowsDLLs#calling-a-windows-dll) gives an implementation to call a message box.

Comment: So you have two options, either create the window yourself `CreateWindow` and pass the hwnd of the same, as shown [here](https://github.com/getlantern/systray/blob/9ddd647aedba71f782bef029a90964301de03480/systray/systray/systray.cpp#L104). Or you can see if passing the desktop hwnd works or not. For the same you can use [GetDesktopWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633504(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Nice ! I have tested the GetDesktopWindow way but I see an error. In the second option, unfortunately I can not do it. Do you have an example of implementation on dedicated Gist or other. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't have a handy gist but I would say search on github and you should get something that you can experiment with

Comment: Please store and print the `lastErr` from `Call` in your `Println`, and tell us what you got. The output may be super laconic, but it will be *some* extra info, and when debugging WinAPI usage, you need all the help you can get.

Comment: You can check how it was done on github.com/lxn/walk, as shown in this [example](https://github.com/lxn/walk/blob/master/examples/notifyicon/notifyicon.go).

Comment: Thanks Adriano for your example, perfect !

Answer (score 2):

### Fields of `NOTIFYICONDATA`

#### hWnd

`hWnd` field of `NOTIFYICONDATA` holds a window handle that is associated with notifyicon itself, as mentioned in MSDN:

> hWnd
>
> A handle to the window that receives notifications associated with an icon in the notification area.

I found that it's necessary to associate a window handle, even if the window is not visible.

`uFlags` tells which fields of `NOTIFYICONDATA` are valid in single command.
As you see there are lots of fields in `NOTIFYICONDATA`, and if you are going to change just the icon of the notifyicon, you can leave other fields unchanged and set only `hIcon` field then pass the whole `NOTIFYICONDATA` to `Shell_NotifyIcon`.
If you want to change both icon and message, just set it to `NIF_MESSAGE|NIF_ICON`.

#### dwState

`dwState` can be used to control icon's visibility. If you specify `NIF_STATE` for `uFlags`, and `NIS_HIDDEN` for `dwState` and `dwStateMask`, it'll make notifyicon hidden.

#### dwStateMask

And in most case, just set `dwStateMask` as same as `dwState`. It just tells which bit of `dwState` is valid for the command:

> The possible values are the same as those for dwState.

### Example

You can find full example I've wrote at here: https://github.com/hallazzang/go-windows-programming/tree/master/example/gui/notifyicon